# the way to determine a request parameter is null

Tags: nsregularexpression

the way to determine a request parameter is null  in spring

Comment: I dont really understand what you are after exactly.  I mean you could simply check for the value.  You have `StringUtils`, or maybe you are after Validating your Input, and you can use the annotation `@NotNull` `@Nullable`, etc  https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Comment: In addition to @Rob Spoor's answer, I'd say this needs to be redesigned. This is a confusing distinction to try to make.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about query or form parameters, then these cannot take value `null`. They are sent as strings; any conversion (e.g. to `int`) is done by the framework or your own application. So if a query parameter is sent in as `?var=null`, then your applications gets `'null'` - a string of length 4 containing the word `null`. So, if your application receives a `null`, then the query / form parameter was not sent.

It's a different story when you're talking about properties in JSON. If the type is simply `String`, `Integer`, etc., then you cannot see the difference between not-present and present as `null`. You can try using `Optional<String>` etc., but I haven't tried that myself. For Jackson you can find more information at https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-optional.

Answer (score 0):

to make sure request parameter is not null and is always present you can use

```
@RequestParam(required = true)
```

This will make sure parameter is always passed

Comment: required = true is the default, you don't have to mention it.